# how to solve No qualifying bean of type 'com.example.test.repository.ConfigRepository' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies autowire

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mongodb

**Following is my directory structure**

1. com.example
2. com.example.common
3. com.example.test
4. com.example.test.repository

**my main spring boot class is as follow**

```
package com.example.test;

@Import({ AutoConfig.class })
@SpringBootApplication
public class testApplication {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(testApplication.class, args);
  }
}
```

**my repository clas**

```
package com.example.test.repository.ConfigRepository;

 @Repository
 public interface ConfigRepository extends MongoRepository<Config, String>, QuerydslPredicateExecutor<Config> {

}
```

This is the error i am getting in debug mode

**DEBUG o.s.c.a.ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner - Ignored because not a concrete top-level class: file [/opt/<folder_name>/<folder_name>/target/classes/com/example/test/repository/ConfigRepository.class]**

**AutoConfig class used in @import is as below**

```
package com.example.common;

@Configuration
@EnableFeignClients
@ComponentScan({ "com.example.common" })
public class AutoConfig {
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your **`ConfigRepository`** class in in **`com.example.test.repository`** this package.

and while providing **`@ComponentScan`**, you are passing this path **`com.example.common`**.

So instead of that you just tried with this **`com.example.test`** path as below.

And also on your **`SpringBootApplication`** file or on your **`Config`** file you can provide **`EnableMongoRepositories`** and setting **`basePackages`** attributes.

```
package com.example.test;

@Import({ AutoConfig.class })
@EnableMongoRepositories(basePackages = {"com.example.test.repository"})
@SpringBootApplication
public class testApplication {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(testApplication.class, args);
  }
}

@Configuration
@EnableFeignClients
@ComponentScan({ "com.example.test" })
public class AutoConfig {
```

More about **`@EnableMongoRepositories`** you will get an idea from [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/mongodb/config/EnableMongoAuditing.html).
This will help you.

Comment: but if i write com.example.test, the classes present in com.example.common will not get scanned and it contains all the configuration class which are required for me.

Comment: it is working now but why it was not working as expected ?

Comment: i mean it should have worked with annotation @repository right ?

Comment: You need to inform container this is my Repository classes. Either of below option.
`@EnableAutoConfiguration` for Spring Boot to figure it out itself
 or
`@EnableMongoRepositories(basePackageScan="com.example.test.repository")` to specify it yourself

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-data-access.html#howto-use-spring-data-repositories

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221005/discussion-between-roshan-and-sagar-gangwal).